# Kind of asset selector

Tags: python, add-on

I'm beginning in blender, addons development 
I want to create simple add-ons who's creating some asset 
And I got a file with some assets, and I want to present them in a panel like the one in the picture. 
I have seen that is created by the function *template_icon_view()*
But how could I link my file and this panel 
Thanks you i'm stuck very hard

[image]

```
    def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    
    data = # There is the problem 

    # Spawn Button
    

    row1 = layout.row()
    row1.template_icon_view(data,show_labels=True, scale=8.0, scale_popup=6.0)
    row1.scale_y = 2.0
```

Comment: Are you planning on using images saved on disk, images saved in the blend file, or dynamically generated icons ?

Comment: I will use images saved on my disk, 
Something like a folder with some images